# ExtJS 4 - Getting an Ext.toolbar's overflow menu

Tags: extjs, menu, extjs4, overflow, toolbar

Is there a way to get the Ext.menu and/or the Ext.Button components used for the overflow menu and "more button" respectively on a Ext.toolbar that has `enableOverflow:true`?

I tried attaching a listener to the toolbar's `overflowchange` event to see if I could use `query()` or `getComponent()` to find the button/menu when it was being shown, but that event does not seem to fire when resizing the toolbar to cause the overflow menu to appear/disappear. I also monitored the toolbar's `add` event to see if that was fired when the "more" button was added to the toolbar, but no luck there either.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what you mean by overflow menu. You should be able to add a button with menu:{items:[...]} underneath it to get your menu that overflow the toolbar.

Comment: Its a feature of extjs toolbars, check [this demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/toolbar/overflow.html) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, with help from the Sencha Forums:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?160597-Getting-a-toolbar-s-overflow-menu

The overflow menu component resides in:
`toolbar.layout.overflowHandler.menu`

Be care though, the `menu` property of `overflowHandler` is only present when the menu is actually needed.